# remove uniform distributed noise with 0 mean and j variance from my data

Tags: signal-processing, variance, means, pattern-recognition, noise

I have the following problem. I have some points coordinates (x, y), that i affected with random noise. We can suppose that my points are:

P1 , P2, P3,..., PN

And after the noise addiction:

P1 + x1, P2 + x2, P3 + x3,..., Pn + xN

Now, I would recognise my points even if they are noised. I mean, I would know that P1 + x1 is P1 point and so on. x1, x2, x3,..., xn are random value (sample) generated from a uniform distributed noise with 0 mean and j variance. j is known (and i can choose it). Do you have any suggest to do this? It is a pattern matchin problem, that i have to fix with not much effort. Thank you all in advice

Comment: Is there a known relationship between the points?

Comment: yes, they are generated by an autoregressor and they follow a pattern